# Bluetooth connectivity issues with hx-hp420 headset

Tags: drivers, updates, bluetooth

i have ubuntu 14.10 and am trying to connect my jam transit Bluetooth headset on a dell inspiron 3520
problem is it doesn't even show and said to update ...update was invalid

am very new to terminal commands and have been researching and find nothing that works..any help would be appreciated

Comment: You could start by opening a terminal window and enter `lsusb` and paste the results.  This will tell us what USB interfaces are present- most bluetooth that are on a wifi card will show as USB

Answer (score 0):

Have you used any other Bluetooth device apart from this headset? If not check whether the driver are installed for Bluetooth. Check the links [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/bluetooth-connect-device.html) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup). These will you idea how to work with the terminal commands.

Comment: dennis@dennis-Inspiron-3520:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:6479 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:07b2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
dennis@dennis-Inspiron-3520:~$

Comment: Any result from `dmesg | grep firmware` as I know this bluetooth device needs broadcom firmware that is only available from Windows drivers